# Using printf to print u32 in C

Tags: c

I trying to print U32 variable in C, not sure what is the write way

```
printf("print_variable %u\n", u32");
```

it gives error, should i force (int)u32 ?

Comment: What is the type of u32? How is it declared?

Comment: What error is produced?

Comment: Gives ***what*** error? Did you not not notice the syntax error in `u32"`? I am sure the compiler did.Your suggested cast `(int)u32` would be wrong anyway: `%u` is *unsigned*.

Comment: @MentoJatt: can you please accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard type `U32`.

Assuming it's an integer type, probably a typedef for a 32-bit unsigned type, you can safely print the value like this:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)u32);
```

I used `unsigned long` rather than `unsigned int` because `unsigned int` can legally be only 16 bits wide. `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits wide, so it can hold any possible value of type `u32` (assuming `u32` is defined sanely). For a 64-bit unsigned type, you can safely use `unsigned long long` and `"%llu"`.

Starting with C99, the standard C library includes a header `<stdint.h>` which defines fixed-width types, including `uint32_t`, which is probably the same thing as your `U32`. I don't suggest making massive modifications to working code just to use the standardized typedefs, but in new code you should probably use `uint32_t`. The standard header `<inttypes.h>` defines macros for use with `printf`, letting you write, as [iharob's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646820/827263):

```
uint32_t u32;
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", u32);
```

(`PRIu32` expands to a string literal; the three string literals `"%"`, `PRIu32`, and `"\n"` are concatenated by the compiler.)

Personally, though, I find the macro names (which are documented in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.8) difficult to remember. I often just convert to some predefined type that I know is wide enough, as I've shown above.

Answer (score 2):

When uncertain what format specifier to use to print some integer:

1. If the type is a specified type in C like `int, unsigned long long, size_t, uint8_t`, etc., best to used the matching specifier `"%d", "%llu", "%zu", "%" PRIu8`, etc.  Many resources list the corresponding type to specifier.

   ```
   #include <inttypes.h>
   printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", u32); // type known to be 32-bit unsigned - no padding.
   ```
2. When the type's relationship to standard types is not clear, yet its sign-ness is known, code can cast to a corresponding wide type.

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>
   printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) u32); // type is known to be some unsigned integer
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `uint32_t`, so include *inttypes.h* and use

```
printf("Value: %" PRIu32 "\n", u32);
```

Comment: Missing a "%" sign

Comment: @chqrlie It wans't there

Comment: IMO it looks ugly